# What's the best thing to do when an email confirmation link expires?

Tags: registration, email

When a user signs up for my web application, they need to click a link in an email to confirm their email address. This link is only valid for a certain number of days.

I've never had a link like this expire in other applications, just to try what would happen if I then tried to sign up again. Currently, the way this is handled in my application, is that the user nees to go through the "forgot password" flow to choose a password. The account has already been created, so registering with the same e-mail address won't work, but the user doesn't have a password yet, so they can't just log in.

What's the best way to handle this in terms of user experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Be honest

Make it clear to the user what happened. They don't need to understand your system, just what is expected to get the job done and move on.

> You signed up but didn't finish the process.
>   <kbd>Resend confirmation link</kbd>

Or whatever that needs to look like.

Comment: I agree with this, but I'd also add the time period they have to finish:
You signed up but didn't finish the process within 3 days, so we need to resend the confirmation link to you.